# How to make existing webpage more structured with 3 divs next to each other

Tags: html, css

I already have a webpage. This can be seen here -> https://plnkr.co/edit/5NWm4E868nXYyixd2SLv?p=preview

It looks fine as it is. Only I don't have much freedom. So I want to make
3 divs where I can change the positions more of certain elements. 
**This is what I want to achieve, its just a picture** ->  https://ibb.co/jDF6hF
This explains it better than words.

This is what I have now : https://plnkr.co/edit/sqpAWK1h6dECDyM1SaAl?p=preview

As you can see, it doesn't look like much of it now. I was wondering if you know a better method to match the picture.

```
#wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item {
  float: left;
  width: 27%;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
  padding: 2%;
}

.imageleft {
  float: left;
  margin: 10% 00% 00% 20%;
}

.circle {
  border: solid 2px #73B7DB;
  background: #73B7DB;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 440%;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-decoration: none;
```

html

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="text" class="item">
    <div id="midleft"><a class="imageleft circle" id="how"><font color="white">Wie</font></a></div>
    <div id="midleft"><a class="imageleft circle" id="how"><font color="white">Wie</font></a></div>
    <div id="midleft"><a class="imageleft circle" id="how"><font color="white">Wie</font></a></div>

  </div>
  <div id="module" class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex
    ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse mole</div>



  <div id="image" class="item"><img class="imageright" src="https://placehold.it/300x200" /></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Now the img on the right is not responsive and it doesn't fix to its container. Just add some css to make img on the right responsive. Like this

```
.imageright {
    max-width:100%;
    height: auto;
 }
```

Comment: Yea it looks a bit better now, but how can you make 2 pictures below each other with different sizes. Because the biggest issue is that the elements are not below each other when you see the page on full screen

Answer (score 0):

I have changed quite a lot. First of all, when you use id's, they must be unique on the page.

I used flexboxes for the layout which makes the page responsive.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.leftColumn {
  width: 20%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.middleColumn {
  width: 55%;
}

.rightColumn {
  width: 20%;
}

.circle {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.circle:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.imageleft {
  color: white;
}

.rightColumn img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.rightColumn img:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="leftColumn">
    <div class="circle">
      <a class="imageleft">Wie</a>
    </div>
    <div class="circle">
      <a class="imageleft">Wie</a>
    </div>
    <div class="circle">
      <a class="imageleft">Wie</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="middleColumn">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex
    ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse mole
  </div>
  <div class="rightColumn">
    <img class="imageright" src="https://placehold.it/300x200" />
    <img class="imageright" src="https://placehold.it/300x200" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The biggest difference between the picture and what you have are the ratios. Try changing the **widths of the .item elements to 15%, 60% and 25%**. Than try to change the **inside widths to relative values** (this can be a bit tricky, I would recommend replacing the circles with images and than setting width:100%).
Also, to see how the .item divs actually look, set the **.item height to 100% or 100vh (viewport height)**.

*Also*, for even more freedom with layouts, you can check-out [css grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) but watch out for browser compatibility.